# What is the easiest way to merge multiple CSV or XML files using VB?

Tags: xml, vb.net, csv

I am trying to find a way to combine 6 CSV or XML files into one. However there is a catch. Each file has 4 common column (related to student details, e.g. student ID, student name etc. ). The rest of the column is different in each file.

I'm trying to figure out a way to combine these files in a way that the 4 common columns will not be duplicated.

Each file have the same number of rows and the same data in the 4 common columns.

Anyone has done something similar to it, or has any advice how to approach it?

Comment: The best algorithm for this depends on the file size. Do the combined files fit easily into memory or are they too large?

Comment: With CSV if you have a header row you need to strip off the header except in the first file.  Usually I use StreamReader and Stream Writer.  If there is no header row you can use a simple windows append method.  With a well formed XML you can only have one Root tag so the best way is using XML Linq to merge the xml files.

Comment: Basically the combined file will not exceed 1mb, so its not a big file

Comment: `6 CSV or XML files` you are probably going to need 2 approaches: one for CSV and one for XML

Comment: CSV or XML which is it? If it's CSV you might be able do this using OleDbDataAdapter... Show us some data from each of your 6 CSV files and i will try to help........

Comment: Do the csv files have headers?

Comment: @Ziemlaj  Don't forget to select\up-vote an answer....

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution that displays the data from two CSV files into a single DataGridView....

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb

Public Class Form1
Private dt As New DataTable
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim folder = "<Path to the folder of your CSV files (don't include the file name, just the path up to the folder)>"
    Dim CnStr = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & folder & ";Extended Properties=""text;HDR=No;FMT=Delimited"";"

    Using Adp As New OleDbDataAdapter("select CSV_1.F1 as CSV1_Col1, CSV_1.F2 as CSV1_Col2, CSV_1.F3 as CSV1_Col3, CSV_1.F4 as CSV1_Col4, CSV_1.F5 as CSV1_Col5, CSV_1.F6 as CSV1_Col6, CSV_2.F5 as CSV2_Col5, CSV_2.F6 as CSV2_Col6, CSV_2.F7 as CSV2_Col7 from [CSV_1.csv] as CSV_1 inner join [CSV_2.csv] As CSV_2 on CSV_1.F1 = CSV_2.F1", CnStr)
        Try
            Adp.Fill(dt)
        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try
    End Using

    DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
End Sub
End Class
```

There are a different number of columns in each CSV file BUT the data in the first 4 columns is the same for each (as you required) The CSV Data for this example should look like this.... (you will of course have to change the code to work with you own CSV files)

CSV_1.csv should look like this....

1, John, Doe, 100, Data From CSV 1, Data From CSV 1

CSV_2.csv should look like this....

1, John, Doe, 100, Data From CSV 2, Data From CSV 2, Data From CSV 2

you can use this example to expand on and include the other CSV file....